# Menu : expand child UL on parent LI click and disable link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open child UL on parent LI click. Problem is that i have links to subpages on parent LI, which needs to be disabled so they don't redirect to subpage, but rather to expand child UL. Where there is no child UL, links on parent LI work normaly.

Code bellow works for disabling default URL and expands child UL, but it also disables child UL LI URL's, which should not.

So when i click on "No child" it should send me to yahoo, but when i click on Yes child it should expand child UL.sub-nav and links in .sub-nav li should work normaly.

Hope it's clear enough

Here's HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">No child</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.altavista.com">Yes child</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav">
                <li><a href="http://www.bing.com">submenu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">No child</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and JS

```
$("nav ul li ul").css("display", "none");
$("nav li a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8bfy7nLn/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target only anchor elements which has a `ul` to display

```js
$("nav li:has(ul) > a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">No child</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.altavista.com">Yes child</a>

      <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li><a href="http://www.bing.com">submenu1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">submenu2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">No child</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```